# Why php pages from nginx server in vmware become blank when lose focus?

Tags: php, nginx, vmware-workstation

My host machine OS is Windows7 and I installed VMware WorkStation on it; in WMware, I established a Linux(CentOS 6.5)+Nginx+MySQL+Php web server. The .html pages are served well when I visit the virtual machine web server from the host machine. But the .php pages are not. The php pages show up when I visit them , but when I move the mouse from the browser to other place and click ( means the php page loses mouse focus), the php pages go blank. What can I do to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

---

Now , not only the php pages, but also the html pages go blank when they lose focus. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome? This might be the automatic tab discarding feature from Chrome. Check the Google [productforums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/zGlxVO9URAo/f0X1eKspEgAJ) for more information.

Comment: No, I'm using a browser based on IE kernel , but not Internet Explorer browser

Comment: Can you post the (simplified) php file you used and a link to your uploaded page?

Comment: <?php   phpinfo();  ?>

Comment: Now , not only the php pages, but also the html pages go blank when they lose focus. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~  @m7913d